# Javascript Selected Values Not Appear

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have listbox and it has values like below.

**Id - Name**

1 - Computer

2 - Mouse

3 - Keyboard

I select all values in listbox.

I only see **3-Keyboard** in my controller.I can not see 1-Computer and 2-Mouse.

```
function GetSelectedValues(){
var Data= {
MyListBox: MyListBox.GetValue(),
};
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/GetValues",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(Data),
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetValues(List<string> MyListBox)
{ 

}
```

Why can't i see all selected values in my controller?

Why do i only see last selected value(3-Keyboard) in my controller ?

Comment: I would expect a function called `MyListBox.GetValue()` to return a single value.

Comment: hi sir , if you have any example about solution please share here thanks

Comment: Show the `GetValue()` function code